# Display data json in dropdown using angular material

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have created an Angular project with angular material and I want to display a list of units inside a dropdown.

the data comes like expected like this :

[image]

this is my .ts code :

```
ListUnits:Array<Unit>=[]

units(){
return this.trq.getListUnit().subscribe(
  (data)=>{
    this.ListUnits.push(data.respModel);
    console.log(this.ListUnits);
  }
)
```

}

and here is my .HTML code :

```
<mat-label>Unite</mat-label>
            <mat-select formControlName= "unite_id" required>
                <mat-option *ngFor="let unit of ListUnits"[value]="unit.id">
                  {{unit.unitName}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
```

but unfortunately, nothing appears
Which are the steps to follow to achieve that?

Comment: Can you attach the API response as JSON snippet to the question? Look like it is a nested array. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pushing array inside array. Instead do this if you want to retain current data in ListUnits

```
this.ListUnits = [...this.ListUnits, ...data.respModel];
```

Otherwise simply assign array from response to ListUnits

```
this.ListUnits = data.respModel;
```

Comment: TimeArray = [{id:1,name:'test1'},{id:2,name:'test2'}];

Answer (score -2):

sample json array declaration

TimeArray = [{id:1,name:'test1'},{id:2,name:'test2'}];